# How can I render an EJS file when making a POST request on express?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My app has the path `\` which is the homepage (working).

It also has a `poems` path where I can see a list of poems (working).

It also has a `poems/new` path where I am called to add a new poem (here is where I need help).

I make a `GET` request to the path `poems/new` on localhost: `http://localhost:3000/poems/new`.

When the page loads, I can see an input element and a button.

**Desired Behavior**

Once I type in a text, I want to:

a) properly make the `POST` request,

b) visit the `poems` page and see the user-typed text as the last item of the list of the poems on the `poems` page.

**Actual Behavior**

The output I see on the terminal is:

```
GET /poems/new 200 28.877 ms - 378
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 3.242 ms - -
POST /poems/new 404 35.646 ms - 149
```

Τhe output I see on the screen is:

`Cannot POST /poems/new`

**App Files**

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "poems",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "start-test-server": "node ./bin/www",
    "test": "jest",
    "test-coverage": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "~2.6.1",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-puppeteer"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-puppeteer": "^4.4.0",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "puppeteer": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

`app.js`:

```
var errorhandler = require('errorhandler');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var poemsRouter = require('./routes/poems')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(errorhandler());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/poems', poemsRouter);

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // only use in development
    res.locals.error = err;
  }
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

`routes/poems.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const poem = require('../public/javascripts/poem')

/* GET poems list page. */
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  await poem.allPoems((allPoems) => {
    res.render('poems', { message: allPoems });
  });
});

/* GET add poem page. */
router.get('/new', function(req, res, next) {
  let content = req.body;
  console.log(content)
  res.render('addPoem', { message: content });
});

/* Add a new poem. */
router.post('/new'), function(req, res, next) {
  const message = req.body.content // not sure if this is even correct
  console.log(message)
 
  res.render('poems') // something like res.render('poems', { message: I_should_put_a_correct_vaiarable_name_here }) should probably happen here
}

module.exports = router;
```

`views/poems.ejs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../public/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <!-- <%= message %> -->
      <%message.forEach(poem => {%>
      <li><%= poem.content %></li>
      <% }) %>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

`views/addPoem.js`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
 </head>
 <body>
    <form action="/poems/new" method="post">
      <!-- <%= message %> -->
      <label for="content"><%=message.content%></label>
      <input type="text" id="content" name="content" value="<%=   message.content %>">
      <button type="submit" value="add poem">add poem</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

`routes/index.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { 
    title: 'Poems',
    message: 'Here you\'ll see poems' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

`views/index.ejs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
    <section id="poems"> <%= message %> </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

`views/error.ejs`:

```
<h1><%= message %></h1>
<h2><%= error.status %></h2>
<pre><%= error.stack %></pre>
```

I'm learning Express at the moment. If there is anything missing and you'd like me to add, please let me know. Also, if I add a link to my project online, I'm not sure how it works. Open to suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a catchall 404 route handler set up for your indexRouter?

Comment: I don't have one. I have installed `errorhandler` from npm, but If I get it right, I'm not using it correctly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this package, but it doesn't seem to cover for 404 not found error types anyway. Could you paste the code for your indexRouter file in your post?

Comment: That's true. It's another issue I'd like to focus on as well. I just pasted the indexRouter file and the relevant `index.ejs` file (plus the `error.ejs` file. - not sure if the last one is needed)

Comment: Ok, you've just closed your parenthesis too early here: router.post('/new'). Should be: router.post('/new', function(req, res, next) { // .. whatever }). Looks like there may be other issues, including in your poem.ejs file, but I'm letting you take a look.